# Javascript is not recognizing my function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I am trying to create a Discord Bot and I need a function. This is my function for checking to see if someone has staff on the server, it's at the top of my file (staff is an array):

```
function checkStaff() {
var staffCheck = "";
var x;
for (x in staff) {
    if(msg.member.roles.find(role => role.name === staff[x])) return true
}
return false
}
```

and then at the bottom, I have

```
var hasStaff = checkStaff()
```

but then I have this error:

```
var hasStaff = checkStaff()
               ^

TypeError: checkStaff is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried doing a snippet but I don't think this is correct:

```js
var staff = ['a', 'b', 'c']
var y = 'a'

function checkStaff() {
  var staffCheck = "";
  var x;
  for (x in staff) {
    if(y === staff[x]) return true
  }
  return false
}

var hasStaff = checkStaff()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This isn't a [mcve], so it's impossible to tell. Looks like no discord-specific code is necessary, so you can you add a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) that we can run to see the issue?

Comment: This is not my exact code because part of it requires discord.js, but this is basically it. A Unexpected token error happens when I run it though, so I'm not sure why that is going wrong too.

Comment: You have an extra `)` on your `if`. But after fixing that, there's no problem. When minimizing code for the purposes of posting here, it should still reproduce the original problem. In other words, you left out something critical, so the question is unanswerable without more information. It's likely that somewhere between the definition and the call, you have a line that reassigns `checkStaff` to something other than a function. Adding `checkStaff = 42;` before calling `checkStaff` in your snippet reproduces the problem.

Comment: There’s nothing here we can use to help.